# Existence of a norm

Tags: general-topology, analysis

K - compact, convex subset of $ \Bbb R^n $
0 $\in$ int K
K is symmetrical to 0. I'm sorry, but i don't know how to write it properly. I mean: $ (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in K \Rightarrow (-x_1,-x_2,...,-x_n) \in K $

I need to prove that there **exists only one** norm determined by K such that K is in this norm an **closed unit sphere**, which has **0** in the middle.

I know that K is bounded from Heine-Borel theorem. I have problems with defining the norm.

Comment: $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: you might want to take a look at the Minkowski's potential for $K$

Comment: @GA316 $ R^n $ you're right, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm needs to be defined only on the unit sphere, all other points have their norm defined via rescaling.

I'd try to study the function $$f(x) = \sup_{t>0 \text{ such that }tx\in K}\|tx\|,$$
then call $$\|x\|_K = \frac{\|x\|}{f(x)}$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ stands for usual norm in $\Bbb R^n$. You need to check that this is indeed a norm, of course.